# How to fix in Blue Prism - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: sap-gui, blueprism

I am trying to automatize SAP with Blue Prism.
The thing is that, for now I can write what I want in the fields I have spied (with SAP MODE) in Business Object.

When I go to Process Studio and I send the data to the Business Object, it goes fine, until it gets to the Write Stage to use this data in the field from SAP, it does not work, it appears:

> Failed to perform step 1 in Write Stage 'Escrever o Nome' on page 'Action 1' - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I'm not using Code Stage yet.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This specific error is clearly documented within [Blue Prism's Knowledge Base](https://portal.blueprism.com/customer-support/support-center#/path/Automation-Design/Application-Integration/SAP/1343520862/Why-do-I-get-Exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-error-while-using-Write-stage-in-SAP.htm):

> ### **Why do I get "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error while using Write stage in SAP?**
>
> This error is due to the "`sapgui/user_scripting_set_readonly`" (SAP GUI
>   Scripting Permission) profle parameter being set to `TRUE`[...]
>
> #### **How to resolve your issue**
>
> Ask your SAP security team or SAP administrator to set the
>   "`sapgui/user_scripting_set_readonly`" to `FALSE`, and also ensure that
>   the scripting is enabled in the SAP server and client.
>
> These changes will allow Blue Prism to write into SAP.

Additionally, you really should review section 2. "Installation and Setup" in the Blue Prism's SAP Implementation Guide v1.4, as it has precise instructions that should be followed during installation and initial configuration in order to avoid errors like these.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip! In my case the problem was writing more characters in SAP field than it could handle.